# Displaying Filtered Data Reactjs

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am new to ReactJS and Javascript in general, and I have stumbled upon an issue with filtering the output data based on what components the user clicked.

Heres the Filter.js component which is outputting the filters. I have commented the part where i got stuck. It's unclear to me what logic should I put inside the .filter() to filter out the apartments displayed under the filter container.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ReactRouter, Link } from 'react-router';

var Filter = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selected: []
    };
  },
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      filterList: [],
      name: '',
      id: '',
      props: []
    };
  },
  render() {
    var selected = [];

    var handleClick = function(i, filterList) {
      this.setState({clicked: i});
      var index = this.state.selected.indexOf(i);
      if (index === -1) {
        this.state.selected.push(i);
      } else {
        this.state.selected.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }

    var className = this.state.clicked ? 'selected' : '';
    return (
      <div id={this.props.id} className="filterCloud quarter-section">
        <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
        <ul>
          {this.props.filterList.filter({/* I dont know what to put in here */}).map(function(listValue, i) {
            return <li
              className={this.state.selected.indexOf(i) > -1 ? 'selected' : ''}
              onClick={handleClick.bind(this, i, this.props.filterList)}
              key={i}>
              {listValue}
            </li>;
          }, this)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

export default Filter;
```

Here's what the filters look like on the app with a few of them selected.
[image]

I want to take the data of the selected filters and filter out the apartments using that data. The best way of doing that is unclear to me.

Comment: `Filter` doesn't render the list of apartments, or does it? What is an example value in `this.props.filterList`? The filtering has to happen in the component that renders the apartment list, not the component that renders the filter.

Comment: @FelixKling, Filter doesn't render the list of apartments, a component named ApartmentContainer renders the Apartment. this.props.filterList contains the filterValues (for example: 'Grad', '>900kn'). Okay that sounds logical, but I still have no idea how to go about doing it. Im guessing I have to connect the two components, and pass the data between the Filter and the ApartmentContainer. If you want, you can take a look at the ApartmentContainer.js here -> http://jsbin.com/vatitiqika/edit?js

Comment: The current filter configuration needs to be part of the state of ancestor of both the `Filter` and `ApartmentContainer` components. `Filter` needs to accept a callback with the the configuration is updated. The configuration is then passed to both `Filter` (for showing which filters are selected) and `ApartmentContainer` (for removing the apartments that don't match the filter).

Comment: @FelixKling, unfortunately that didn't help me since I couldnt find a way of transferring that logic into code.